# Need to add Date via php in header of table

Tags: php, html

I have a page where i want to display yesterday's date in the header of the table. I tried this code but not able to display the date value.
Please Help!

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr><th colspan='9'>DATA  <?php echo date("d/M/Y",strtotime("-1 days")); ?></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>COLUMN A</th>
<th>COLUMN B</th>
</tr>";
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to what @Ranjith said, you could also do this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysqli_select_db($con,"db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
?>
  <table border='1' align='center'>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='9'>
      DATA  
      <?=date("d/M/Y",strtotime("-1 days"));?>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>COLUMN A</th>
    <th>COLUMN B</th>
  </tr>";
  </table>";
<?
mysqli_close($con);
```

in PHP-code you can use `?>` and `<?` to switch between PHP and HTML. The `<?=` is a short form for an `echo`.

Comment: Thank You ! Will try the same .

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to use `echo` inside php string.
try this :

```
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr><th colspan='9'>DATA  ".date("d/M/Y",strtotime("-1 days"))."</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>COLUMN A</th>
<th>COLUMN B</th>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Thank You ! Got o/p as required.